# Understanding the proof of Schur's theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> [image]

The proof comes from Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, Spence. I don't understand one step in this proof. How do we know that $T_{W^{\perp}}$ splits? I am confused because it is not obvious to me that "the characteristic polynomial of $T_{W^{\perp}}$ divides the one of $T$" implies that $T_{W^{\perp}}$  splits.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits by hypothesis, hence any (non constant) divisor of this polynomial also splits: recall that linear polynomials are irreducible elements of the UFD $k[X]$, $k$ being any field.

Comment: What do you mean by UFD $k[X]$ ?

Comment: The ring $k[X]$ is a unique factorization domain (even a Euclidean ring actually). I use the unique factorization theorem to deduce that any divisor of a split polynomial is also split.

Comment: @shk910: What Suzet is saying is that if $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of $T$, then it splitting means that $p(x)=\lambda \prod_{i=1}^n (x-\alpha_i)$ for some appropriate $\lambda,\alpha_i\in \mathbb{C}$. If $p'$ divides $p$, then use the algorithm for polynomial division to see that $p'$ must have the same form.